# Multiple metadata within a single mosaic dataset

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, dem, metadata, mosaic

I am creating a mosaic dataset consisting of thousands of different DEMs.  These will make up a single State, however I need the Counties to be able to hold their own metadata.  Each raster contains its own metadata, however when mosaicked together the mosaic dataset contains no metadata.  I can import an .xml to the description and to the overviews, but this limits me to a single description for each raster within the dataset.  Does anyone know how to make multiple metadata select-able within a single mosaic dataset.

Note: I am using ArcGis 10.1 and sharing these to a ArcGis 10.2 server through an image service. 
Each county mosaic works seamlessly, holding its own metadata.  I just cannot figure out how to get different metadata to display when identifying a particular county.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure we have enough information about what kind of map application you're using which would help determine your options. An image service can only have one .xml metadata record. The only die-hard solution I can think of is to create one mosaic dataset per county, and then host each as an image service. An alternative way would be to manipulate the code of the map application you're using so that it requests a particular .xml file path stored as an attribute in each DEM (using PHP).

Comment: I have created a mosaic dataset per county and uploaded as an image service as you had suggested.  I am now trying to create a single mosaic including all the counties of Maryland.  My idea is that the user should be able to upload a single image service and identify each county within, eliminating the need to download and import 23 counties separately. I can do it as a map service by appending metadata to the overviews, however the map service is only an .mxd and cannot be uploaded to open source applications such as QGIS, which is a must. Maybe image service is the wrong way to go...?